# How can I fix the `invalid recursive type Tarea` error when trying to make `subtareas` a pointer to `ListaDeTareas` in Go?

Tags: go

I need subtareas in the struct Tarea to be a pointer to ListaDeTareas, but is not working. I have `invalid recursive type Tarea`

```
type Tarea struct {
    nombre    string
    duracion  float32

    subtareas *ListaDeTareas
}

type ListaDeTareas[T Tarea] struct {
    elementos listadetareas.LinkedList[Tarea]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't use type parameter `T` in `ListaDeTareas`. And removing it will fix the issue.

```golang
type Tarea struct {
    nombre    string
    duracion  float32

    subtareas *ListaDeTareas
}

type ListaDeTareas struct {
    elementos listadetareas.LinkedList[Tarea]
}
```